# How Can I make Apple App Clip Smart Banner show?

Tags: ios, apple-appclips, smart-app-banner

I recently developed an App Clip and published it on the App Store. I've created the default app clip experience and put the apple-app-site-association file in the .well-known directory. The JSON looks like this.

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
            "apps": ["T3Y3F3XXXX.it.company.my-app"],
             "components": []
           }
       ]
   },

    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["T3Y3F3XXXX.it.company.my-app.Clip"]
    }
}
```

This is what I've done on App Store Connect:
[image: Default Experience]

[image: App]

[image: Domain URL Status]

My meta looks like this:

```
<meta name="ARShades" content="app-id=1586660000, app-clip-bundle-id=it.company.my-app.Clip, app-clip-display=card">
```

The problem is the Smart App Banner won't show. I think I've met all of the Apple stated requirements here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/supporting_invocations_from_your_website_and_the_messages_app
[image: Requirements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below JSON in apple-app-site-association file :

```
{ "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "T3Y3F3XXXX.it.company.my-app" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]    },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["T3Y3F3XXXX.it.company.my-app.Clip"]
    } 
}
```

Comment: Isn't the bundle ID under appclips supposed to end with .Clip? Like: T3Y3F3XXXX.it.company.my-app.Clip

Comment: Right, that's a typo. Please update it with .Clip extension and give it a try.

Comment: Sure, I'll let you know! Thanks!

Comment: I've had no luck yet. I've tried with the new AASA file you gave me. The site I'm trying to make it show is this: https://arshadesapp.spaarkly.it/

Comment: Could you also try updating the meta tag as below :
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1586661818, app-clip-bundle-id=it.spaarkly.ARShades-demo.Clip">